# How to get Month, Year and Days in postgresql between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns in the sql table which is startdate and enddate

```
Startdate           Enddate
27-12-2015 22:30    03-01-2016 19:30
01-01-2016 12:45    09-02-2016 18:30
```

I want to get the resultant table like

```
Startdate           Enddate            Month     year   days
27-12-2015 22:30    03-01-2016 19:30   Dec       2015   5
27-12-2015 22:30    03-01-2016 19:30   Jan       2016   3
01-01-2016 12:45    09-02-2016 18:30   Jan       2016   31
01-01-2016 12:45    09-02-2016 18:30   Feb       2016   9
```

Comment: What should be the "Month" value for e.g. startdate = 2017-01-01 and enddate = 2017-06-29? Or the year value for startdate = 2010-04-01 and enddate = 2017-02-01?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for the first month value should be jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun with the days in the month including the startdate and enddate. and for the second date year is 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017 with the maonths and days respectively.

Comment: Please add a comment before make a close request.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In the result table you have February. How did it get there? What does it all mean? I know you want that table but from what you wrote, we could just as well hardcode it and offer it as a solution. I have a suspicion on what you want, but i'm not sure. If I post this answer, I might just get a downvote because that's not what you're asking.

Comment: @AlexanderMP thanks for correcting in the question table it is till february month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough solution would be to generate all the days and then aggregate (count) them. It works, but it's rough on memory. If it's not crucial, this solution would definitely work. The alternative is to generate a months series and make a day diff with a lot of conditions, if performance is critical.

```
SELECT
    dates.startdate::DATE,
    dates.enddate::DATE,
    to_char(days.s, 'Mon') AS mon,
    to_char(days.s, 'YYYY') AS yr,
    count(1) AS d
FROM dates
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(dates.startdate, dates.enddate, INTERVAL '1 day') s
) days
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

In any case, here is the second variant, that loops through months instead (faster, harder to understand):

```
SELECT
    dates.startdate::DATE,
    dates.enddate::DATE,
    to_char(months.startdate, 'Mon') AS mon,
    to_char(months.startdate, 'YYYY') AS yr,
    least(
        months.enddate::DATE - dates.startdate::DATE + 1, -- takes care of first month
        dates.enddate::DATE - months.startdate::DATE + 1, -- takes care of last month
        months.enddate::DATE - months.startdate::DATE + 1 -- takes care of full months from the middle of the intervals
    ) AS "days"
FROM dates
-- get months as first day in that month
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series(
        (to_char(dates.startdate, 'YYYY-MM-') || '01')::DATE, 
        (to_char(dates.enddate + INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM-') || '01')::DATE - 1, INTERVAL '1 month') m
) days
-- get months as start date and end date
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        days.m::DATE AS startdate,
        (days.m + INTERVAL '1 month')::DATE - 1 AS enddate
) months
```

Comment: I added the "faster" version, just in case

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case a plpgsql function can provide better performance than a plain sql query.

```
create or replace function get_months(startdate date, enddate date)
returns table (mon text, year int, days int)
language plpgsql as $$
declare d date;
begin
    d:= date_trunc('month', startdate);
    while d < enddate loop
        mon:= to_char(d, 'Mon');
        year:= to_char(d, 'YYYY');
        days:= case 
            when d+ '1month'::interval > enddate then enddate- d+ 1
            when d < startdate then (d+ '1month'::interval)::date- startdate
            else (d+ '1month'::interval)::date- d
        end;
        return next;
        d:= d+ '1month'::interval;
    end loop;
end
$$;
```

Test:

```
with my_table(startdate, enddate) as (
    values
    ('2015-12-27 22:30', '2016-01-03 19:30'),
    ('2016-01-01 12:45', '2016-02-09 18:30')
)

select *
from my_table, 
lateral get_months(startdate::date, enddate::date)

    startdate     |     enddate      | mon | year | days 
------------------+------------------+-----+------+------
 2015-12-27 22:30 | 2016-01-03 19:30 | Dec | 2015 |    5
 2015-12-27 22:30 | 2016-01-03 19:30 | Jan | 2016 |    3
 2016-01-01 12:45 | 2016-02-09 18:30 | Jan | 2016 |   31
 2016-01-01 12:45 | 2016-02-09 18:30 | Feb | 2016 |    9
(4 rows)
```